# How to make node-fetch to extract a specific parameter only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, fetch

I am trying to extract the priceChange of BNB rather than get the whole detail of the API (https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBUSD)

I am using node-fetch model in Node js. The code is:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBUSD')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`json`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#json) method to get the data on `node-fetch`.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBUSD')
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(instrument => {
    console.log(instrument.priceChange)
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Api that you provided is have json format.It is not a text format.Therefore you need to use
`res.json()` instead of using `res.text()`.

```
fetch("https://api.binance.us/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBUSD")
.then((res)=>{
    return res.json();
}).then((newdata)=>{
    console.log(newdata.askPrice);
})
```